# Navigate the "DOM" of a string as though it was html with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to take a string that is legal HTML and extract some data from it, based on tags and their attributes. I know that this is possible with jQuery and that it has several built-in methods for this, but I'm trying out Angular and I want to avoid using jQuery unless I really, really need to. Does Angular provide its own set of functions for this?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Show us exactly what the HTML string is and what you want to extract from it.  This can even be done with plain Javascript, but we can answer a lot more efficiently if you show us exactly what problem you're trying to solve rather than having to describe all possible things you can extract from an HTML string.

Comment: The string is a webpage from my server that I fetch with AJAX, i.e. a big fat long HTML file.

Comment: And what you are you trying to extract from it?

Comment: The HTML file contains some `<a>` tags wrapped inside `<span>`s with certain classes/ids etc. I basically need to run `$("big long selector").each(` on the string, having first parsed it as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with even plain Javascript.  Here's a simple example.  We could answer much more specifically if you showed us exactly what you're trying to extract from the HTML string.  Here's a working snippet example that shows the basic concept:

```js
var htmlStr = '<div><div class="item">Bear</div><div class="item">Wolf</div></div>';

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = htmlStr;
var items = div.querySelectorAll(".item");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  document.write(items[i].innerHTML + "<br>");
}
```

Angular contains a subset of jQuery called jqLite which is documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).  The `.find()` in jqLite is limited to only search for tag names so `.querySelectorAll()` which is built into all modern browsers these days would be much more capable.

Comment: Does Angular provide its own set of functions for this?

Comment: @Bluefire - Angular contains a subset of jQuery called jqLite, documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).  The `.find()` in jqLite is less capable than `querySelectorAll()` which is built into browsers these days.